# how to change tkinter scrollbar color

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, colors, scrollbar

hi I'm making a text editor with python but how can I change tkinters scroll bar color

I tried using bg but it does not work

## Here's my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

# creating our root
root = Tk()
root.title("Text Editor")
root.geometry("1200x640")
root.config(bg="black")

# creating our frame
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

# creating our vertical scroll bar
text_scroll = Scrollbar(my_frame)
text_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# creating our horizantal scroll bar
h_scroll = Scrollbar(my_frame, orient="horizontal")
h_scroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

# creating our text box
my_text = Text(my_frame, width=97, height=25, font=("Helvetica", 16), selectbackground="aqua",         
selectforeground="blue", undo=True, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set, wrap="none",                             
xscrollcommand=h_scroll.set, bg="#333", fg="aqua")
my_text.pack()

# configure our scroll bar
text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)
h_scroll.config(command=my_text.xview)

# main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: I'm using windows

Answer (score 0):

Use `tkinter.ttk` is a module that is used to style the `tkinter` widgets

> I'm making a text editor with python but how can I change tkinters
> scroll bar color?

- Add `import ttk` namespace.
- Add `style = ttk.Style()`
- Add `style.theme_use('classic'`
- Add `style.configure` for both vertical and horizontal.

Snipppet:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk

# creating our root
root = Tk()
root.title("Text Editor")
root.geometry("1200x640")
root.config(bg="black")


style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('classic')
style.configure('Horizontal.TScrollbar',
                background='green',
                bordercolr='red',
                arrowcolor='white'
                )

style.configure('Vertical.TScrollbar',
                background='green',
                bordercolr='red',
                arrowcolor='white'
                )
 
# creating our frame
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=5) 

# creating our vertical scroll bar
text_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(my_frame, orient="vertical")
text_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# creating our horizantal scroll bar
h_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(my_frame, orient="horizontal")
h_scroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

# creating our text box
my_text = Text(my_frame, width=97,
               height=25, font=("Helvetica", 16),
               #selectbackground="aqua",         
               #selectforeground="blue",
               undo=True,
               xscrollcommand=h_scroll.set,
               yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set,
               wrap="none",                             
               bg="#333", fg="aqua")
my_text.pack()

# configure our scroll bar
text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)
h_scroll.config(command=my_text.xview)
 

# main loop
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]